# Android - GraphView - ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, android-graphview

I have been working with the GraphView Libary. There is data stored in an ArrayList which is saved to SharedPreferences onStop(). When my Intent / class to draw the graph is called it reads the previously stored data from SharedPreferences and saves it to an Array which will be used to draw the graph.

But the graph looks like so:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/12j5j.jpg

The only data added to my ArrayList is 14. I have already done some research about Array Lists and and found that 10 is the initial capacity. Maybe thats the problem?

Code to restore the ArrayList in my Main Activity:

```
SharedPreferences arrayGraph = getSharedPreferences("arrayGraph_temp_1", 0);
int arraySize = arrayGraph.getInt("arrayGraph_temp_1_size", 0);

for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {

    float temp = arrayGraph.getFloat("temp_" + i, 0);
    arrayGraph_temp_1.add(i, temp);
}
```

Code to add a float variable to ArrayList:

```
arrayGraph_temp_1.add(arraySize, x);
```

Code which saves the ArrayList to SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences arrayGraph = getSharedPreferences("arrayGraph_temp_1", 0);  
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = arrayGraph.edit();                          

int listSize = arrayGraph_temp_1.size();
editor.putInt("arrayGraph_temp_1_size", listSize);

for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {

    float temp = arrayGraph_temp_1.get(i);
    editor.putFloat("temp_" + i, temp);
}

editor.commit();
```

Code to restore data in class to draw graph:

```
SharedPreferences arrayGraph = getSharedPreferences("arrayGraph_temp_1", 0);
int arraySize = arrayGraph.getInt("arrayGraph_temp_1_size", 0);

GraphView.GraphViewData[] data;
data = new GraphView.GraphViewData[arraySize];

for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {

    float temp = arrayGraph.getFloat("temp_" + i, 0);
    data[i] = new GraphView.GraphViewData(i, temp);

}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you verify that your save loop is actually getting all of the values (i.e. `listSize` is correct and `arrayGraph_temp_1.get(i)` is actually returning value data for that position `i`?

Comment: I just checked both points. The strange thing is, if there is one element (in my case float variable) added to the ArrayList its lenght is 13.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case.  The `size()` method should tell you how many elements are in the `ArrayList`.  Did you construct the `ArrayList` with an initial capacity?

Comment: No, I constructed the ArrayList like this: `ArrayList<Float> arrayGraph_temp_1 = new ArrayList();`  Also: the elements which are displayed as 0 in the graph have the value null and those in the middle are 1. I have no idea why!

Comment: How are you adding your initial elements to the array (not when restoring from the shared preference)?

Comment: I just updated my initial post.

Comment: Try just calling `arrayGraph_temp_1.add(x)` rather than specifying the size as the index.  The `add(E object)` method will automatically append the new value to the end.  Perhaps your `arraySize` variable is being incorrectly initialized?

Comment: Already tried that before. When I call `arrayGraph_temp_1.add(x)` `x` is added to the end of `arrayGraph_temp_1`. The graph then looks like vertical reflected. I just wonder where these 12 additional values come from.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow that last comment.  Perhaps let's take a step back, what exactly are you trying to graph?

Comment: There is an ArrayList which contains float variables. When a Button is clicked an other class is called wich draws a BarChart. So the first Activity saves the ArrayList to SharedPreferences using the code above. Now the second Activity reads from these SharedPreferences to create an Array. This Array will be used to draw the graph.

Comment: Ok, but what is the goal of the graph?  To show each individual point separately?  Are you creating a `GraphSeries` out of the array of data?  You could also just attach your data into a `Bundle` and attach it to the `Intent` used to start the second `Activity` rather than go through a preference.  There would be less overhead.  Of course, if you need your data to persist beyond just the graph then having it in the pref would be ok.

Comment: The Array / ArrayList contains temperature values. So there is a `GraphSeries` created. `GraphViewSeries seriesRnd = new GraphViewSeries("test", null, data);`. The data has to persist beyond Activity life. So SharedPreferences is a good way to go I think. But it is all working fine. The only thing that bothers me are the 12 additional values in my Array / ArrayList when there is only one added. -.-

Comment: Yeah, something is definitely not right there.  I've never seen an issue with ArrayList reporting back more than what you have added to it.  Sorry, not sure what to tell you.

Comment: So, finally I found where the problem occured. I am parsing an .xml file to get the values, which will be written to my ArrayList. The .xml file contains 16 different values and I was working on the 13th value. For some reason all values up to the point where I parse the String to a float an add it to my ArrayList are also added to my List. I'd better start a new Question?!